# Why does the following trivial protobuf-net code not work correctly?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to figure out how to work with protobuf-net. The below example is trivial on purpose. It does not reflect a real life application.

Please, observe:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(ms, 1234);
Serializer.Serialize(ms, 5678);
ms.Position = 0;
var n1 = Serializer.Deserialize<int>(ms);
var n2 = Serializer.Deserialize<int>(ms);
Debug.WriteLine(n1);
Debug.WriteLine(n2);
```

It outputs:

```
5678
0
```

What is wrong?

I am using protobuf-net 2.4.0

Comment: Protobuf has no concept of "packets" or similar, i.e. it can't _split_. It just reads 'till the end.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You wrote two integers to a single buffer. When deserializing/reading, protobuf will read _the whole stream_ to deserialize, so it sees the integer, extracts it, sees another integer again and overwrites the previously read integer, and then after reading the whole buffer returns this (second) integer. Your second `Deserialize` only sees an empty stream since your first call already read it fully. You'd need to implement your own splitting-algorithm to deserialize multiple values from a single buffer.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So, if I place the two integers as members in a `Payload` class, then it works. Would you mind arranging your comment as an answer and give an example of how to fix it without introducing a `Payload` type? I would like to credit you.

Comment: Suppose I need to write 1,000,000 integers to the stream. Then I want to read them and process one by one. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, Protobuf doesn't have a concept of 'packets' the way you'd expect. A stream is always fully read on deserialization, previously read values are overriden when they're seen again in the stream. Therefore, writing multiple messages to a single stream won't work the way you do it. Unfortunately, there is no easy fix, you have to implement packet-splitting yourself. One way to do it is to prefix any message by it's length, and split the input accordingly. This works good for bigger message, but your message consists only of a single int which would scale very badly. I'd really suggest not using protobuf at all in this scenario, instead you could take a look at their int-serialization routine (some dynamic-length encoding if I remember correctly) and serialize and deserialize single ints yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitConverter for converting integers to byte arrays and then sending the arrays to memorystream:

Following link can help:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/convert-integer-to-byte-array-in-C-Sharp/

then once you have the array of bytearrays, you can do this:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
for(int temp = 0; temp < bytArray.Length; temp++)
  memoryStream.Write(byteArray[temp], 0, byteArray[temp].Length);
```

Finally, use Protobuff to have memorystream.